# Catch and change locale Excel date format when importing to ISO8601

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, excel

I am implemeting an excel import where besides others, a date field is imported to salesforce and inserted as a record. Now I have e.g. an excel sheet where I have a date Format like 01.02.2020 or 02/01/2020 which salesforce won't accept, following the ISO8601 in formattedDateTime.
Is there a best practice way to handle such an issue?
I saw that there are some [possobilities to do so](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-formatted-date-time/documentation), but I think this doesn't apply to my issue.

I am building up a datatable via the .js-controller

```
cmp.set('v.customObjectTableColumns', [
                                          {label: 'Name', fieldName: 'Name', type: 'text'},
                                          {label: 'Quantity', fieldName: 'Quantity__c', type: 'number'},
                                          {label: 'Date', fieldName: 'Date__c', type: 'date'}]);
```

And have the Date__c with type 'date'. The Object type of this custom field is also date.
I am reading in the values from the excel sheet here via the .js-helper

```
 fr.onload = $A.getCallback(function() {
            let fileContents = fr.result;
            let workbook = XLSX.read(fileContents, {
                type: 'binary'
            });
            let rows = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[workbook.SheetNames[0]]);
            let customObjects = [];

            for (let i = 0, len = rows.length; i < len; i++) {

                for (let j = 1; j <= 5; j++) {
                    let customObject = {
                        sobjectType: 'customObject__c',
                        Name: rows[i]['Name'],
                        Quantity__c: rows[i]['Quantity']
                        Date__c: rows[i]['Date']
                    };
                    customObjects.push(customObject);
                }
            }
            cmp.set("v.customObjects", customObjects);
        });
```

I think I need to catch the date in the .js-controller or set it even in the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this function I found on https://gist.github.com/christopherscott/2782634:

```
getJsDateFromExcel: function(excelDateValue) {

            var date = new Date((excelDateValue - (25567 + 2)) * 86400 * 1000);
            var localTime = new Date(date.getTime() + (new Date()).getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
            return localTime;
 }
```

It handles the five-digit-date-format of excel quite well. Turns it into a local time form which can be handled by Salesfoce.

Calling it in my eventHandler:

```
Date__c: self.getJsDateFromExcel(rows[i]['Date'])
```

Comment: Important to note, though: not all versions of Excel have the same epoch! Old versions of Excel for Mac use 1904 as the epoch date.

Comment: Yes that is true, it is noted in the linked thread.

Comment: Nice solution, solid answer! Next time tho, I'd say put some more sample dates in your question, it would have helped me (& others) answer your question better.

Answer (score 1):

I'm far from a lightning expert, but I'd try parsing the date inside your controller.

(Sample code take from [How to Format a JS date](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34015511/3865753), modified)

```
var options = { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };
var someDate  = new Date('3-1-19');

console.log(someDate.toLocaleDateString("en-US", options); // 3/1/2019
```

I'd wrap the code needed in a function & call it on your excel values before handing them over to the server. `parse` should be generic enough to understand any dates passed along.

Switching out `toLocaleString` to [`toIsoString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) should return the date in a string salesforce should understand.

```
function ParseDate(date) {
    var someDate  = new Date(date);

    return someDate.toISOString();
}
```

Then, your "parser" looks like this:

```
Date__c: ParseDate(rows[i]['Date']) // "1.1.2019" -> "2019-01-01T05:00:00.000Z"
```

Comment: I like the approach, a few notes though, Your sample code never actually uses the options you define. It's also important to specify source and destination locales. Last, the output formats I see in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) seem to support the [format](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm) I would expect SFDC to require

Comment: Whoops, copied the wrong code. Wasn't sure if it was a locale issue so much as a formatting issue, focus more on the format. Not sure what you're trying to say with your last line. That the output from the `parse` function isn't valid for SF?

Comment: One more thing that might improve the answer, how does the parser know which value is the day, month and year? for instance, [in US the format is usually mm/dd/yyyy but in EU it's dd/mm/yyyy](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/68844/date-format-in-uk-vs-us). In your code you specify 3/19/19 but what if an end user were to upload 19/3/19 (this is more of a problem with something like 01/02/2019, is it feb 1 or jan 2)?

Comment: If I wrote code to cover every possibility, I'dk ask for more than just rep lol. Looking at that MDN page, "`parse()` assumes a local time zone", but I'm sure there are better libraries which handle time zones much better than the standard. However I didn't want to link to an external library, and I generally don't cover extra problems outside the scope of the OP's question. If the OP came back and said "this doesnt work bc I have 4 different time zones" I'd adjust my answer. This should "just work" enough to  demonstrate how to modify the OP's code.

Comment: Thanks, your hints helped me find a solution, I will post.